# A series of fantasy books, different (but also not really) brother and sister protagonists in every book

Tags: story-identification, books, magic, reincarnation

I'm looking for the series that is described in the title.

Other details that I remember is that in book one, where at the start the world was kind of normal, the sister saved the brother from drowning (I think.) They were both mages/witches, but the brother gets his power later on. In a different entry in the series, at the end the brother is capable of some ancient magic or something like this. If I remember correctly there were different pairs of siblings in each book, but also somehow the same (possibly reincarnation.)

EDIT 1:
I read it like 10 years ago, so i can't really remember anything in detail. They were physical books, probably around 200-300 pages each, nothing comes to mind in terms of the cover art. I think in book two or three the main enemy was either a principal of a magic school or the owner of the mansion where the siblings stayed at. It's the same person, it's that i just don't remember if this was a magic school or the mansion. He was later defeated by the brother who had the magic to counter him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  When did you read these?  Do you remember any character or place names, or any of the significant conflicts or adversaries they face?  If these were physical books, were they paperback or hardcover?  Roughly how many pages?  Do you remember any of the cover art?

Comment: I read it like 10 years ago, so i can't really remember anything in detail. They were physical books, probably around 200-300 pages each, nothing comes to mind in terms of the cover art. I think in book two or three the main enemy was either a principal of a magic school or the owner of the mansion where the siblings stayed at. It's the same person it's that i just don't remember if this was a magic school or the mansion. He was later defeated by the brother who had the magic to counter him.

Comment: The Chrestomanci series by Diana Wynne Jones? https://www.fantasticfiction.com/j/diana-wynne-jones/chrestomanci/

Answer (score 4):

The ***[Chrestomanci Series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/43763-chrestomanci)*** by Diana Wynne Jones.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrestomanci):

> *Chrestomanci*, sometimes branded *The Worlds of Chrestomanci*, is a heptalogy of children's fantasy books written by British author Diana Wynne Jones, published from 1977 to 2006. In the context of the parallel universe setting of the books, Chrestomanci refers to both the British government office that is responsible for supervising the use of magic and Chrestomanci Castle in southern England, which is both residence and headquarters.

> The label "The Worlds of Chrestomanci" on some late 20th century editions alludes to their general setting, a multiverse called the "Related Worlds". The worlds have branched from common ancestors at important events in history such as English and French victories in the Battle of Agincourt, or the success or failure of the Gunpowder plot. Some people can move between worlds, at least in spirit, and twelve Series of similar worlds have been labelled in the English of the stories. It is common for people to have parallel selves in other worlds. The principal setting for the series is World 12A.
>
> World 12A is reminiscent of Britain during the Edwardian Era. There are known to be other worlds with British governments, probably all of series 12 and some others; even more worlds have an England in or near Europe. The Chrestomanci has representatives in some other worlds but does not know all other worlds. Indeed, *Witch Week* is set in a world even closer to ours, yet its existence is a surprise to Chrestomanci Christopher Chant and he cannot easily identify it.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. However, you'll need to wait until at least 48 hour have passed since you asked the question, as the site doesn't allow self-answers to be marked as accepted any earlier than that.